# constraint layout strange behavior

Tags: android, android-layout, responsive-design, android-constraintlayout

[image: large screen]
[image: small screen]

I want  to make Ui that contains two card views next to each others horizontally but in smaller sizes screen the spaces between this aren't showing they appear to be touching each other, i added guidelines for left and right side of the screen to detect the start margin and end margin ,I'm setting both cards to wrap_content so they should fit inside the screen 
Edit: I'm Using Constraint layout as root layout

```
  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/id_sale_card"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view7">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
                android:background="@drawable/card_images"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/sale" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id_sale_txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="98dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
                android:text="$0.00"
                android:textColor="#ff565659" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="109dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
                android:text="Sale"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="#ff565659"
                android:textSize="12sp" />


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/id_card_earning"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view7">


            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/card_images"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/earning"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"

                    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"
                    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.65" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/id_earning_txt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
                    android:text="$0.00"
                    android:textColor="#ff565659"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView59"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="Earning"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="#ff565659"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: you haven't constrained the two cards to each other. You have only constrained start of the first to left guideline and end of second to right guideline. This may overlap the cards if screen size is smaller

Comment: can you post full xml code? especially "@+id/guideline". because in your image cant see any vertical guideline between two cardviews.

Comment: @kaveh this is the whole code i want to test , even when i add constraints between them part of the right card is out of the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) with `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent` to tell your card views to Stop at some point, and getting space between them by doing that.

**Here is the layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.65" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_earning_txt1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
            android:text="$0.00"
            android:textColor="#ff565659"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Earning"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#ff565659"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/second"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/first">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.65" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_earning_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
            android:text="$0.00"
            android:textColor="#ff565659"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView59"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Earning"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#ff565659"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.45" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.55" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**It will look like this:**

[image]

Now, please notice that this image is taken from the layout editor and not real phone - I wanted you to see the guidelines.

It will work on your device as well.

Comment: Sure,if this was helpful can you accept the answer? So others with the same problem could use it.

Comment: sir isn't using alot of nested layouts consume a lot of memory

Comment: You can replace  your nested views with fragments, design your fragments(card view in your case) and no more nested view.

Comment: but i think this will add a lot of complexity , Ex: this layout is for home fragment so you want me to include like 4 fragments in the home fragment correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: For every time you will practice the next time will be less hard. You can stay with this layout if it is working good (the only nested objects are the card views that contains all other images)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/id_sale_card"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/id_card_earning" //include this line
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view7">
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/id_card_earning"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/id_sale_card"   //include this line
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view7">
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Also if you want your card views to fill whole screen you can pass `android:layout_width="0dp"` which is basically match constraint.

Comment: thanks sir but still the two cards merge on the small screens

Comment: could you try removing guideline and write parent in their place so the code should look like this:- app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" //cardview sale app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent" //cardview earning

Comment: and also did you try android:layout_width="0dp" (which is basically match constraint)

Comment: Oh and you also forgot to include layout inside your sales card view so all your views of sales card view must not be displaying correctly.

Comment: @Mistart did it helped?